# How to ignore the nested objects that have null value or don't exist

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the below aggregations query.

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "selected_brand": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "brandId": "b1d28821-3730-4266-8f55-eb69596004fb"
                }
            }
        },
        "sponsorshipSets": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "sponsorshipSets"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "sponsorships": {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "sponsorshipSets.sponsorships"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "count": {
                            "value_count": {
                                "field": "sponsorshipSets.sponsorships.id"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The response is the below.

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2980,
      "relation": "eq"
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "selected_brand": {
      "doc_count": 314
    },
    "sponsorshipSets": {
      "doc_count": 2635,
      "sponsorships": {
        "doc_count": 1076,
        "count": {
          "value": 1076
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response shows the count of sponsorship documents is 1076, now I want to retrieve the documents these documents and tried with the below query.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "sponsorshipSets",
                    "query": {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "sponsorshipSets.sponsorships",
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must_not": [
                                        {
                                            "match": {
                                                "sponsorshipSets.sponsorships": "null"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "brandId": "b1d28821-3730-4266-8f55-eb69596004fb"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The interesting thing for the second query is the hits below is only 82.

```
"hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 82,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
```

What I really want is to retrieve the count of all the sponsorshipSets.sponsorships documents that are not null or not exist. SponsorshipSets can be missing as well.

Find below the abbreviated template.

```
{
  "index_patterns": "campaigns*",
  "order": 4,
  "version": 4,
  "aliases": {
    "campaigns": {

    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "properties": {
      "brandId": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "sponsorshipSets": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "sponsorships": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: So it looks like the aggregations query is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`exists`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) query to filter such documents. Below query should help.

### Query Request:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "nested":{
               "path":"sponsorshipSets",
               "query":{
                  "nested":{
                     "path":"sponsorshipSets.sponsorships",
                     "query":{
                        "bool":{
                           "must_not":[
                              {
                                 "exists":{
                                    "field":"sponsorshipSets.sponsorships"
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "filter":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "brandId":"b1d28821-3730-4266-8f55-eb69596004fb"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

This should return all three scenarios where your document JSON structure would be

- `sponsorshipSets.sponsorships: {}` i.e. you have empty structure for `sponsorships`
- `sponsorshipSets.sponsorships: null` i.e. the value is set as `null`
- Or your document doesn't have `sponsorships` field in first place.

You don't need to use any aggregations for this as ES would return you the count of such documents in `hits.total.value` of the response.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Yes! You helped a lot and also points for explaining further as I found the same way to do it :) Thanks! Although your exact query won't work as it seems, check my solution here, https://gist.github.com/weare8/d10d427c1c74ff0d97530f9b121c21eb

Comment: @GeorgeTaskos I think that's one and the same. Initially I thought of mentioning the one you've had saying `you can simplify it..` as...but I mentioned this one coz you asked that in the question and perhaps you've had more conditions in bool query :). But I guess, both logically gets interpreted in similar manner.